# Getting multiple hashes from a single request in rails & SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, request

I want to do something a bit like -

```
@apples  = Fruit.find :all, :conditions => ["type = ?", "apple"]
@pears   = Fruit.find :all, :conditions => ["type = ?", "pear"]
@tomatos = Fruit.find :all, :conditions => ["type = ?", "tomato"]
```

The problem is this takes 3 DB requests. Is there a way to combine these so it only makes 1 request but gets all the required info?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Actually this is the best you can do. You can do one request, but then split rsult by groups with Ruby

Comment: Ah, no magic RoR trick! I knew you could split the results in ruby but this can be taxing if you have a large DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said already in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755441/getting-multiple-hashes-from-a-single-request-in-rails-sql#comment-8008849), running a big query and fetching all entries and then selecting them via Ruby can be a pain in the ass. There a few reasons to let MySQL (or whatever database you are using) do the job:

1. If you have 1 million entries, Ruby have to instantiate 1 million ActiveRecord objects. This eats up memory very fast, and can make your application unusable, especially in production. Imagine 100 users accessing your site, and each of your dynos (hopefully you have more than one) has to load 1 million entries and compare 1 million strings!
2. Let the database do their jobs. They like their jobs, and they are really good at it. In fact they are optimized to run such queries. If your database seems to be slow, check your indices and tweak them if necessary.
3. It makes your code ugly and maybe even unreadable having a big query and then splitting it up, instead of 3 variables, each defined and fetched in it's own row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to get all fruits whose type may be "apple" or "pear" or "tomato" and then in ruby iterate to create the required collection of Fruits.

```
   @fruits = Fruit.find :all, :conditions => ["type = ? or type =? or type =? , "apple", "pear", "tomata"]
```

Then in ruby you can do something like this (very basic).

```
 @apples = @fruits.select{|f| f.type == "apple"}
```

Comment: First of all Rails is smart enough to do something like this: `@fruits = Fruit.find(:all, :conditions => { :type => %w[apple pear tomato]})` and secondly this approach is much slower then hitting the database 3 times. If your database has 1 million entries, Ruby has to instantiate 1 million objects!

Comment: Performance is a whole different issue. Whether instantiating objects or doing selections in ruby will be faster(as in memory) than database hit(network or i/o call) as far I know but it may differ based on specific scenario.